# Docker CMD to start Haproxy in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, haproxy, dockerfile

Here is my CMD command in my Dockerfile for haproxy:

```
CMD ["/etc/init.d/haproxy"]
```

Now when I run the image the following happens:

```
...
Successfully built 2eb6549e0a22
root@server:/# docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 81:81 -p 443:443 -p 1988:1988 --name haproxy -h haproxy user/haproxy
09b510c4df712414d8855d3e0fb27b7e35d5c5c2f0f9b07f7f29c8efdb93e852
root@server:/# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
09b510c4df71        user/haproxy   "/etc/init.d/haproxy"   5 seconds ago       Exited (2) 4 seconds ago                       haproxy
```

As you can see it exits straight away. How do I keep it running?

Comment: just a suggestion, for debugging purposes: when invoking "docker run", temporally leave out the "-d" (deamon mode). In my case, I did this and got some info from haproxy, complaining about some issues with my config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your `user/haproxy` inherit from the [haproxy container](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/) in the main docker repo? If so the command `haproxy` should be in the PATH and it includes a `-f` flag for running it in the foreground.

I usually specify the config file too, so my CMD looks like:

```
haproxy -d -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

Comment: So CMD ["haproxy -d -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"]?

Comment: Hmm, under COMMAND I get `"haproxy -f /usr/loca"   4 seconds ago`, as if String command is too long to be an argument.

Comment: @KarlMorrison It's not too long, it's just displayed like that. You can use the `--no-trunc` flag to see the whole command. That will work if you actually have a haproxy config file at that location. You could get one there with ADD or COPY in your docker file or just by mounting a volume when you run it `-v haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`

Comment: Ok! I'll have to `-it` into the container see what the issue is.

Comment: @KarlMorrison Any luck?

Comment: Indeed still sitting with it. Different problem though hehe. I realized my .cfg was in another location! Works now so thanks :)